# Wordpress permalink redirection

Tags: php, html, wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

I am trying to create a theme for Wordpress where I have
0. landing page with static info and 6 latest posts. When user clicks on post title it is supposed to open it
1. all articles page with the same clickable function

What I've done so far
0. Pages index.php and page.php(this is the articles list page). In Wordpress settings those pages are added to "Pages" and page.php is child of index.php
1. This is my code in both files.

```
    <?php
    if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <article class="post">
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
       <?php the_content(); ?>
    </article>

    endwhile;

    else :
        echo '<p>No content found</p>';

    endif;
    ?>
```

The problem:
It redirects me to the homepage again, just adding post ID to the link. The post IS actually displayed at the bottom of the page, but the previous content is still showing up (I mean, homepage is still there, just with the post at the bottom).
So, what may be wrong?

P.S. I don't have any active plugins and I have default .htaccess

Comment: it's hard to understand Your problem ... page.php is not child of index.php

Comment: @Michael In "Pages" section in Wordpress config I added index.php as parent template for page.php.Mentioned this just in case it may have any influence)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is hard to understand, have you tried saving your Permalinks again and reproducing the problem in a private browser screen? (301 redirects get be cached as long as possible in your browser, so that might be a reason you (still) get redirected)

Comment: I've tried, no changes. The problem is that I want page to display just my post, nothing else. But it only changes the div where my posts loop is. So, I mean, how to make it to delete all the content and only to show up a post? Is it JS or sth else?)